# Alfresco integration with Angular 7

Tags: angular, alfresco, opencmis

I'm working to migrate an application from Struts to Angular 7. Current application has a page in which users can see the folder structure and files in Alfresco and select a document. The information about the selected document will then be saved to DB. This application uses OpenCMIS API to query Alfresco.

When migrating to Angular, I'm looking to get rid of the OpenCMIS layer and see if there is a way to integrate Alfresco directly with the Angular component. I have seen documentation about ADF, but unfortunately as per the documentation, it works only with Alfresco version 5.2 and about. But ours is 3.3. Is there a better way to integrate Angular with an older version of Alfresco other than to using OpenCMIS queries?

Comment: What's wrong with going via CMIS? It's an open standard, well known, fairly easy to use etc. Without knowing your objection to CMIS, it's hard to suggest what else to try....

Comment: upgrade alfresco to a newer version?

Comment: Why don't you go with the API? Simply go to http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/ and see what's available out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

With version 3.3 of Alfresco, your choice is either CMIS, out-of-the-box web scripts, or custom web scripts.

You should definitely consider upgrading as you are running WAY behind the current release.

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in going through this custom web script [implementation](https://techkneak.blogspot.com/2020/05/bootstrap-your-alfresco-share.html)